# Error in eval() when using randomForest in R

Tags: r, regression, random-forest

I am trying to use the `randomForest` command

I have a sparse matrix, called counts, of single-cell expression data, and another variable, identity, which has the type of cell

```
counts <- t(as.matrix(CountsMatrix))

names(counts) <- make.names(names(counts))

smp_size <- floor(nrow(counts)*0.7)
train_ind <- sample(c(1:nrow(counts)), smp_size)

x_train <- counts[train_ind,]
x_test <- counts[-train_ind,]

y_train <- identity[train_ind]
y_test <- identity[-train_ind]

train_set <- cbind(data.frame(Identity = y_train), as.data.frame(x_train))
forest <- randomForest(Identity ~., data = train_set)
```

I have put all the data together in a data frame, and the line `names(counts) <- make.names(names(counts))` was added from my attempts to fix my error.

When running this code I get the error:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object '0610005C13Rik' not found
```

My data has 16519 columns each with a name similar to `0610005C13Rik`, and I do not know how to rename all of them if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try with some example dataset, avoiding using function names as a variable, identity is a function, so:

```
library(randomForest)
library(Seurat)
CountsMatrix = pbmc_small[["RNA"]]@data
ident = factor(as.numeric(Idents(pbmc_small)==1))
```

Just fit it:

```
fit = randomForest(ident ~ .,data=cbind(ident,counts))
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'HLA-DRA' not found
```

Here we use make.names like you did:

```
counts <- t(as.matrix(CountsMatrix))
names(counts) <- make.names(names(counts))
```

You have a matrix, names() does not work. We can look at it:

```
head(names(counts))
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

It's the column names you need to fix:

```
colnames(counts) <- make.names(colnames(counts))

smp_size <- floor(nrow(counts)*0.7)
train_ind <- sample(c(1:nrow(counts)), smp_size)

x_train <- counts[train_ind,]
x_test <- counts[-train_ind,]

y_train <- ident[train_ind]
y_test <- ident[-train_ind]

train_set <- cbind(data.frame(Identity = y_train), as.data.frame(x_train))
forest <- randomForest(Identity ~., data = train_set)
```

Or you can simply do:

```
forest <- randomForest(x=x_train,y=y_train)
```